# How do I add a line break in this PHP email output?

Tags: php, syntax-error, line-breaks

I'm trying to modify a Craft CMS plugin to slightly customise the email output of a contact form script. I have very limited PHP skills and so far the answers I've found online haven't worked for me in this case. The relevant portion of the script is below:

```
$email->body      = "From: " . $message->fromName . " (" . $message->fromEmail . ")" . $message->message;
```

I would like to add a double line break after the "fromEmail" in parenthesis so that the "message" starts below rather than on the same line. The script currently outputs "fromName", "fromEmail", and "message" all on the same line.

I've tried various ways of adding \n\n or "\n\n" and keep getting PHP errors - it may just be a syntax problem. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plain text email:

```
$email->body      = "From: " . $message->fromName . " (" . $message->fromEmail . ")\n\n" . $message->message;
```

HTML email:

```
$email->body      = "From: " . $message->fromName . " (" . $message->fromEmail . ")<br><br>" . $message->message;
```

Comment: Oh, two options. You are just full 'o sugar, aren't ya shoog?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i was going to add `PHP_EOL` but i did not want to be accused of showing off

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `\n` try adding `\n\r` or use `<br>`, if you work with HTML-E-Mails.

Tip:
Also, I ran into the same problem several time, when looking at my emails in MS-Outlook. That program tends to eliminate "unnecessary" line-breaks, so you have to watch for a notice above your e-mail in Outlook. You can then click on it to show all line-breaks, as intended.